# Error: Cannot find module './util/eventLoader'

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am currently writing a `Discord bot`. When I was trying to start the bot I recieved the following error message:

> Error: Cannot find module './util/eventLoader'

after some research I wasn't able to find a suitable solution. I'm using `Visual Studio Code` as my `code editor`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @DustedDustTR! We need to see the code you wrote if you want us to find a problem with it. Maybe you could add that to your question by editing it. This might help you as well: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Have a nice day!